# xml to c# classes not serializing correctly

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I am getting zero results on the list of results when this is serialized. I am actually trying to get the geometry of the result but for some reason all the results are not showing and when i do a count i get 0.

here is a snippet of xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PlaceSearchResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <result>
  <name>Premier Inn Manchester Deansgate Locks</name>
  <vicinity>Medlock Street, Manchester</vicinity>
  <type>lodging</type>
  <type>restaurant</type>
  <type>food</type>
  <type>point_of_interest</type>
  <type>establishment</type>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>53.4713048</lat>
    <lng>-2.2474693</lng>
   </location>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>53.4711143</lat>
     <lng>-2.2475661</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>53.4718764</lat>
     <lng>-2.2473777</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
  </geometry>
```

C#

```
    if (webResponse.error == null)
    {
        print(webResponse.text);
        PlacesApiQueryResponse placesObject = LoadFromText(webResponse.text);
        print(placesObject.results.Count);

        foreach(var entity in placesObject.results)
        {
            print(entity.geometry.location.lat + " | " + entity.geometry.location.lng);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        print(webResponse.error);
    }
}

public static PlacesApiQueryResponse LoadFromText(string text)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PlacesApiQueryResponse), new XmlRootAttribute("PlaceSearchResponse"));
    return serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(text)) as PlacesApiQueryResponse;
}
}

public class Location
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
}

public class Geometry
{
    public Location location { get; set; }
}

public class OpeningHours
{
    public bool open_now { get; set; }
}

public class Photo
{
    public int height { get; set; }
    public List<object> html_attributions { get; set; }
    public string photo_reference { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
}

public class AltId
{
    public string place_id { get; set; }
    public string scope { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public OpeningHours opening_hours { get; set; }
    public List<Photo> photos { get; set; }
    public string place_id { get; set; }
    public string scope { get; set; }
    public List<AltId> alt_ids { get; set; }
    public string reference { get; set; }
    public List<string> types { get; set; }
    public string vicinity { get; set; }
    public string rating { get; set; }
}

public class PlacesApiQueryResponse
{
    public List<object> html_attributions { get; set; }
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What came before `if (webResponse.error == null)` in the original C# code? Also, what are you serializing and where are you serializing it?

Comment: Rename "PlacesApiQueryResponse" class as "PlaceSearchResponse" or add XMLElement decoration to the class.

Comment: @Telans This is not the issue.

Comment: Xml serialization blows donkey blanks.  Use the NetDataContractSerializer or xaml serialization instead.

Comment: @EdPlunkett it is unity www making the url call. I am pulling google places api into classes to use.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I am taking a text xml response and trying to pull it into classes, the response is passed into the load function which serializes it. am i going at this wrong?

Comment: @user1552172 What load function?

Comment: public static PlacesApiQueryResponse LoadFromText(string text)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PlacesApiQueryResponse), new XmlRootAttribute("PlaceSearchResponse"));
    return serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(text)) as PlacesApiQueryResponse;
}

Comment: @user1552172 can you put that in the question? Code is very hard to read in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Your classes just don't correspond to the input XML in respect to how `XmlSerializer` works. The issues is with `List<T>` serialization, where a two-level XML is required, like this:

```
<list-element>
   <item-element>
      … content goes here …
   </item-element>
   …
</list-element>
```

You have to change both the XML and the corresponding classes, e.g.:

```
<results> ← new element groupping all <result> elements
   <result>…</result>
</result>
```

and the class:

```
public class PlacesApiQueryResponse
{
    public List<object> html_attributions { get; set; }

    // attribute to tell XmlSerializer how are the item-elements named
    [XmlArrayItem("result")]
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I cant change googles xml response, i can set an attribute.

Comment: I agree that this would work except i cant change the xml :(